# Programmatic UITextField and programmatically releasing the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield

I've looked in many places and it seems everyone uses IB. I like it, but find it more fun writing it all out. This being said, I'm having difficulty dropping my keyboard after editing is done. Here's an example.

```
-(void)textStuff
{

    UITextField *someField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];//not true size
}
```

Here I've tried the resign firstresponder and even a BOOL to say are you editing, YES, then make that keyboard first responder dangit....oh, you're done editing...good, now resign that first responder.....none has worked as of yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you set the delegate of the field using `someField.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1).

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

2).
you set the delegate method.

```
 SOMEFIELD.text =delegate;
```

And .h file

```
@interface yourViewController  : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and in .m file you add the delegate method of the textfield

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: This was everything. Both above answers combined worked, but here it is in whole. Thanks Daxesh.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is set someField's delegate your view controller and implement following method,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Don't have the street cred to select the right answers. It is a combination of both, telling the delegate to become the view and then adding the BOOL. Thanks guys for the fast response. I'm hoping one day I can contribute at least in saying those are the right answers. Thanks again all.